# what format blueimp-gallery.add expects for list parameter

Tags: gallery, blueimp

I tried to load additional slides to my blueimp-gallery instance collected by infinityscroll using a callback and the galler.add()-method. In the blueimp-gallery readme there is a just a list parameter listed to the .add(list) method but I can't figure out what kind of list it expects.
Could be a list of a-tags or list list of javascript-objects, I couldn't get it work.

Answer (score 0):

ok found it out, it's a array of html-nodes like or jquery selector